# Run php function from index.php

Tags: php, function, redirect

This is on file : PurchaseSiteLoggedIn.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <header>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>Palm User Login-Registration</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        </header>

        <script src=""></script>

        <body>
                <?php
                session_start();
                if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])){
                }
                else{
                header("Location: http://localhost/loginregister.html");
                }
                ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

If the user is not logged in he/she will be redirected to another page.(the loginregister.html)
This code works fine. What I wanna do is replace:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   }
   else{
   header("Location: http://localhost/loginregister.html");
   }
?>
```

with `DoAnonymousCheck();` (a random name for the function) so that the code looks cleaner
//
Ideally i would want to have the body of the DoAnonymousCheck on a different file.

I tried somthing like:
I added
`<script src='DoAnonymCheck.php'></script>`
in the PurchaseSiteLoggedIn.php folder.

And in another folder that i called DoAnonymCheck.php I had

```
<?php
function DoAnonymCheck(){
   session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   }
   else{
   header("Location: http://localhost/loginregister.html");
   }
}
?>
```

It didnt work though (i guess in `<script src></script>` you can only add a .js folder)

Comment: `i guess in <script src></script> you can only add a .js folder`...yes that's correct

Comment: Unrelated fyi, your `header`s should really be `head`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "import" a PHP script with a `script` tag, because all PHP code is executed on the server side before it shows up in the client browser. However, you can use `include` or `require` to load other PHP scripts. [Code Example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)